# Windows Server 2016 - Defender Firewall is not blockling inbound UDP packets to application?

Tags: windows, firewall

Good evening!

**The problem:** I have a Windows Server 2016 machine with Windows Defender Firewall enabled, I am trying to block inbound UDP packets to a custom network application.

**What I've tried:** I deleted every single rule under *Inbound Rules* tab tab in Advanced Security but yet the inbound packets *(from external network)* are still able to reach the application?
[image]

Comment: Enable logging and check the logs maybe?

Comment: @Zoredache Windows Firewall logs indicates that there are no inbound UDP packets, I can tell that TCP traffic is getting blocked though. TCPDump for Windows claims that UDP packets are coming in (I can verify this since I'm the sender and they show up in the main application). Why can't Windows see the incoming UDP packets?

Comment: Are you sure the server uses the Public Profile ? You did the same configuration in the other tabs ?

Comment: @Swisstone That's correct, the default action (block) for outbound traffic is set in Domain, Private and Public profiles.